# How to display a program output through a "dialog" window

Tags: bash, dialog

How can I reroute a program's output to a `dialog` window instead of `stdout` or `stderr` using bash?

I don't want to capture that output to a variable by using `variable=$(appname)` and display it afterwards by using `dialog --msgbox`. I want to have something like a runtime rerouting so that the program's output is displayed in that `dialog` window as it is generated. Not after it's finished.

Is that possible?

Thank you!

Comment: `dialog --msgbox "$(appname)" 5 20`?

Comment: @Cyrus I don't think this is what the OP wants. OP wants to display the output as it is generated. Consider a long running command...

Comment: @FedonKadifeli, exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `--progressbox` option is what you are seeking. See this example:

```
{ while true ; do date ; sleep 2 ; done ; } | dialog --progressbox 30 100
```

It will display the data as it is printed to `stdout`. In your case, you can pipe your application's output to the `dialog` command like this:

```
appname 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 30 100
```

If you want to display an `OK` button, when the output from `appname` finishes, you can use the `--programbox` option instead.

See [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/man1/dialog.1.html) for details.

Comment: Can this display more than one line? The larger the `dialog` window, the more lines are shown for example?

Comment: @Stormlord . I think you are asking about the *height* and *width* parameters. See man page.

Comment: I will. Thank you.

Comment: FedonKadifeli, `--programbox` works fine for displaying another program's output. Is there any way or any other dialog option that we can use in order to pass input to the program whose output is displayed?

Comment: You can always pipe another app's output or redirect from a file like this: `app1 | appname 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 30 100` or `appname <inputfile 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 30 100`